# Google App Script. How can i get hyperlink name?

Tags: google-apps-script

Have troubles with extracting url from text in google document. I found method `getLinkUrl(offset)`. It works fine, but if i for example add link not directly to text but via menu item `Insert -> Link` i can specify some name for link, for example name, that will be displayed in text will be `StackOverflow` and the link is `https://stackoverflow.com`, so when i use method `getLinkUrl()` i will get hyperlink but not the name. I need to get position of this link on text, so i need to get this word `StackOverflow` but i didn't find corresponding method for this. 
Is someone know how i can get this word or its start and end indexes?

I know about `attributeIndices` property which contains indexes of starting of special formatting of text and it can be used in this case, but if link is last word in paragraph, there is no any more attribute index in this array, so i can not determine length of this word.

Would be appreciate for any advice)

Comment: Hello @АлександрБрянский, so let me understand more clearly your questions - you are trying to retrieve the **link** from a hyperlink represented by a word which is the last one in a paragraph? Cheers!

Comment: Hi) Yeah, exactly. I need to get not url, but link name. There must be some way to do it

Comment: Hello @АлександрБрянский, if you know the position at which the text for the link starts, you can retrieve it by using the `getText()` method, which will in fact, retrieve the text, even though it has a `url` attached to it. Does this work for your situation? Cheers!